# Django add new field on model if new object is created from another model

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-mysql

I have two models:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="test")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class UserScore(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resultat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When I create a new exam create dynamically I want a new field on my userscore model for all user.

Comment: Since the exam is unique for each `User`, why not have the score in the same model?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Django signals for that 
eg.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
def create_userscore(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserScore.objects.create()
post_save.connect(create_userscore(), sender=Exam)
```

this will create a UserScore object everytime Exam objects get created

Comment: this methode will implemented in exam class or userscore classe ?

Comment: because you have to pass the instance of user

Comment: Thanks for your help, i dont want to create all userscore object everytime Exam is created, i want just create one new field exemple :
new exam = new resultat

Comment: I didn't get your question actually, but as far as i can understand your question you can add the resultat field to Exam model .

Comment: Thks you, just for more clarification, what i need is when i'm on the admin page for my website i want when i create new exam for all users i need new resultat field be created automatically in my userscore table this is my purpose for example :
new exam 1 = new resultat 1 
new exam 2 = new resulatat 2
etc......